# serialize SPListItemCollection through WCF sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, json, splistitemcollection

My question is simple, how to get ( or retrieve ) json serialized SPListItemCollection through WCF service ?
tried to use NewtonSoft for .Net, but it's throw an exception when try to serialized it.

I google it but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search, it seems there is no direct way, so I used the REST API in my WCF to retrieve the list , and it's done the job.